# Does RuntimeBinderException in the CSharp namespace indicate DLR language dependence?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

Considering the largely language-agnostic .NET Framework including class library and runtime, and the fact the DLR is supported by multiple languages, I find it odd that a subclassed `System.Dynamic.DynamicObject` in a C# application actually throws an Exception that's in the `CSharp` namespace.  I catch the following exception when trying to access a member on `dynamic` that doesn't exist at runtime:

`{Name = "RuntimeBinderException" FullName = "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException"}`

Is the  `RuntimeBinderException` exception specific to C# and if so, must each language implement its own binder exception?  It strikes me as odd why the exception is not in a more general namespace and that makes me wonder "what's up"?

I'm running in Debug mode in VS 2012 Express on .NET 4.5.  The application was built in C#.

Comment: It's odd for sure, but I wouldn't say it creates a _dependance_ since any language in the CLR can use the `Microsoft.CSharp` namespace.

Comment: @John K: just curious - when trying something comparable in vb.net or some other compatible language, what does it throw or what error is produced?  Does it throw a "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException" simply because you're in a c# environment, or is that the exception type thrown regardless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting an exception in the `CSharp` namespace is because the DLR has determined that the `dynamic` object in question is a C# object, and has passed it off to the C# runtime binder for handling.

Each language that supports the DLR would need its own implementation of this runtime binding system, and each would depend on the semantics of the language. For example, languages like JScript, which supports on-the-fly property and method creation, would probably not throw an exception on every binding failure, but set or return a new property.

So the answer is, yes, each language that wanted to throw an exception on a DLR binding failure would have to implement it separately.

(As another example: VB.NET's support for dynamic objects works exactly the same as it's existing late binding support; you would get the same errors from a DLR binding failure as you would a late-binding `IDispatch` failure, for example, so it didn't need a separate exception.)